# setInterval doesnt tigger inner script on first time run

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Maybe I'm not properly understanding `setInterval` but I have made a kind of slideshow script, as below:

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $('.slide').fadeOut('slow').delay(200);
    $('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000);
    i++;
    if(i == 5){
        i = 0;
    }

}, 4000);
```

This works, except for the first run - no slides will display for the first 4 seconds.

See Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vpa89snf/6/

Is there anyway I can trigger whats inside the setInterval function when it runs the first time round?

Comment: Because the 'entire block' will run only after 4 seconds. Since the slides are inside the block it will run only after that.

Comment: Read this http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the function and not wait for the 4 first seconds:

```
var i = 0;

function doSomething() {
    $('.slide').fadeOut('slow').delay(200);
    $('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000);
    i = (i + 1) % 5;
}

$document.ready(function () {
    setInterval(doSomething, 4000);
    doSomething(); // run it!
});
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/L31ub7nd/)

Comment: I'm wondering why shouldn't we call 'doSomething' first and then setInterval. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Nope, it will work the same.
BTW, you can create a setIntervalAndRunNowFunction(func, interval){func(); setInterval(func,interval);}

Comment: Yeah, I thought so! Thanks for confirming. If you could do that, then the code should be "much straightforward" for the OP/future-reader.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeOut` instead of `setInterval` for better performance, inspect the sample below:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpa89snf/21/)

```
var i = -1;
var totalSlide = $('.slide').length-1;
var slideTimer = 0;
function nextFrame() {
    i == totalSlide ? i = -1 : i;
    i++;
    $('.slide').fadeOut(200);
    $('.slide').eq(i).fadeIn(200);
    slideTimer = setTimeout(nextFrame,4000);
}

$('#holder').addClass('isAni');
nextFrame();

// play / pause animation
$('#holder').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('isAni') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('isAni');
        clearTimeout(slideTimer);
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('isAni');
        nextFrame();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how setInterval is executed. It runs your function after x milliseconds set as 2nd parameter.
What you have to do in order to show the first slide is to have the 1rst slide fadein like below:

```
var i = 0;

$('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000);
i++;

setInterval(function() {

...

}, 4000);
```